# You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm getting this error on this piece of code. `You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull. "uidString" is nullable.`  When I annotate it with @NonNull and @PrimaryKey, `An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey`

What's up?

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity(tableName = "player_profiles")
public class PlayerGameProfile implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey
    public String uidString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;
```

Comment: `When I annotate it with @NonNull, An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey` Did you annotate it with __both__ or just `@NonNull`?

Comment: The latter is with both.  I tired changing the order too

Comment: And make sure you import the correct NonNull package: `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;`

Comment: Yes, sorry for the sloppy code paste, all are present.  OP edited

Comment: I have tried out what you did and I did not get any compile or build errors. The problem is elsewhere and not with the annotations. Also, I used the AndroidX annotations and **NOT** the support annotations

Comment: Do you have the latest libraries? as per Shankha507 works fine (and also tried swapping position of @NonNull in relation to @PrimaryKey). I'm using     `implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.1'` and 
    `annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.1'`. I did come accross what appeared to be the same issue with earlier libraries.

Answer (score 6):

For Java you should annotate with `@android.support.annotation.NonNull`

Delete the other NonNull import you are using yet and change it to

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

Then use both annotations

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason `androidx.annotation.NonNull` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had:

```
@PrimaryKey @NonNull var reasonId: String? = Constants.EMPTY_STRING,
```

instead of:

```
@PrimaryKey @NonNull var reasonId: String = Constants.EMPTY_STRING,
```

Comment: If you are writing kotlin you shouldn't need `@NonNull` provided you use the non-nullable type

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the primary key with the Entity like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "player_profiles",
        primaryKeys = { "uidString" })
```

After that annotate your primary key with `@NonNull` in the class below.

```
@NonNull
public String uidString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: :( still getting the second error about atleast 1 primary key

Comment: Also make sure that you try the other import package for NonNull mentioned in my comment to OP: `import android.support.annotation.NonNull`

Answer (score 0):

check the case sensitiveness it should be "@NonNull" and not "@Nonnull"
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

Comment: That is, in fact, what the text in the question says.